# ProviderManifestToken = "2012" and transient errors in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I have had a couple of cases where the value of the ProviderManifestToken attribute (Edmx/Runtime/StorageModels/Schema) in my EDMX file is updated to 2012 after performing the 'Update Model from Database' operation.

I have multiple EDMX files in my solution and the others are not affected. The result is that I get the following error which prevents Visual Studio from building my solution.

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Model.ssdl(2,93) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different from '2012' that was encountered earlier.
```

When I update all of the ProviderManifestToken attributes in the solution to 2012, I can then build successfully. There are however 'transient' errors similar to the following which do not break the build but have caused some confusion on our team.

```
Error 168: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance. The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance.
```

I think that putting up with the transient errors (all attributes set to 2012) is the lesser of two evils. Leaving them as 2008 would mean that the build would break whenever someone updates a model from the database.

It would be great to get rid of the transient errors though. Can anyone provide any tips on how to do this?